# Find the values of a,b and c in a polynomial $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$

Tags: polynomials

The question is this :

A polynomial $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ where $a,b,c$ are some rational numbers, has $1 + \sqrt3$ as one of the zeroes and also $p(2) = -2$. Find the values of $a,b$ and $c$.

Please give appropriate explanation too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What I would try first: Since you know a zero, you know that you can write $p(x)=a(x-1-\sqrt3)(x-d)$ for some number $d$ (being the other zero). Now plug in the value $x=2$ and see what you can learn.

Comment: I don't understand the significance of putting the value of x as 2.
I tried but I didn't get anything meaningful. :/

Comment: Well, better suggestions came forward. My suggestion seems to require more work to get anywhere, so it seems pointless to continue it now. My larger point, though, is that it often helps to just try something and see what you can find out to get a handle on the pronlem. If you just stare at it without trying some calculations, you get nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to solve the system
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
p(1+\sqrt{3})=0\\
p(2)=-2
\end{array}
\right.$$
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
a(1+\sqrt{3})^2+b(1+\sqrt{3})+c=0\\
4a+2b+c=-2
\end{array}
\right.$$
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
a(4+2\sqrt{3})+b(1+\sqrt{3})+c=0\\
4a+2b+c=-2
\end{array}
\right.$$
Since $a,b,c$ are rationals the first equation "splits" in the first two equations of the following system:
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
4a+b+c=0\\
2a+b=0\\
4a+2b+c=-2
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: I didn't understand how and why the the first equation "splits" into two. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: You can collect $\sqrt{3}$: $$(4a+b+c)+\sqrt{3}(2a+b)=0\ ,$$ now you have to notice that the term in brackets are rational, so in order for their sum to be 0 the have to be both 0.

Comment: Oh, I see. :)
Thanks, I got the answer. 
But, frankly speaking, the method used by @TonyK is much faster and we don't even require the value of $p(2)$ :D

Comment: I agree, that's much faster :)

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Let $f$ be *any* polynomial with rational coefficients (it doesn't have to be quadratic), and suppose $f$ has a root $s+\sqrt t$ with $s$ and $t$ rational and $\sqrt t$ irrational. Then $f$ also has a root $s-\sqrt t$.

Comment: Ah, clever. Such an elementary result, yet it wasn't in my tool kit. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this lead me to the answer. :)